# Consider the image measure $\gamma=\lambda\circ u^{-1}$. Determine $\gamma([0,a])$, $\gamma([-a,a])$ and $\gamma([a,a+1])$ for all $a\geq 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and let
>   $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $u(x)=|x|$. Consider the image
>   measure $\gamma=\lambda\circ u^{-1}$. Determine $\gamma([0,a])$,
>   $\gamma([-a,a])$ and $\gamma([a,a+1])$ for all $a\geq 0$

I'm a little uncertain about this, since I'm not sure if I'm getting the notation right. Would the following be correct?

For the first one we have $\gamma([0,a])=\lambda(u^{-1}([0,a]))=\lambda([-a,a])=a-(-a)=2a$

I'm not sure about the second one, since $-a$ is not defined for $u^{-1}$, while $a$ is. But my guess would be it gives the null set, hence $\gamma([-a,a])=\lambda(Ø)=0$?

And for the last one $\gamma([a,a+1])=\lambda(u^{-1}([a,a+1]))=\lambda([-a-1,-a]\cup[a,a+1])=\lambda([-a-1,-a])+\lambda([a,a+1])=-a-(-a-1) +(a+1)-a=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is right, and the second and third one are the same: By definition, $$u^{-1}[-a,a]=\left\{x:-a\leq |x|\leq a\right\}$$
since $a\geq 0$, the condition $-a\leq |x|$ is trivial, and thus
$$u^{-1}[-a,a]=\left\{x:|x|\leq a\right\}=[-a,a]$$
so
$$\gamma[-a,a]=\lambda(u^{-1}[-a,a])=\lambda[-a,a]=2a$$
and the third one is correct:
$$\gamma[a,a+1]=\lambda(u^{-1}[a,a+1])=\lambda([-a-1,-a]\cup[a,a+1])=2$$